# Empty contract.methods Using web3 JS 1.0.0-beta30

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, dapp-development

I'm attempting to call a method on a locally deployed contract with the following code using web3 JS 1.0.0-beta30.

```
const tradingCardABI = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('build/contracts/TradingCard.json')).abi;

const ownerAddress = process.env.OWNER_ADDRESS || '0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57';
const contractAddress = process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS || '0xf25186b5081ff5ce73482ad761db0eb0d25abfbf';

const tradingCardContract = new web3.eth.Contract(tradingCardABI, contractAddress);

console.log(`contract json interface=${JSON.stringify(tradingCardContract.options.jsonInterface)}`);
console.log(`contract models=${JSON.stringify(tradingCardContract.methods)}`);
```

I get `contract methods={}` in the console. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried the same and was wondering why the `methods object` is `empty`. I tried to console.log the `instance.methods` directly which gave me an error, that ... can't be shown.

Then I simply tried to call a function from this "empty" object and it worked as it supposed to.

So the answer is, that you can call the methods even if they don't show in your json output.

Use the following code to call the methods:

```
YOURINSTANCE.methods.YOUR_METHOD().call().then(ret => {
    console.log(ret);
});
```